# How is ETA2 and LAMBDA produced when running the predict function in the lavaan package? How can I check the dimensions of these two matrices?

Tags: r-lavaan

I'm getting this error: "Error in tcrossprod(ETA2, LAMBDA) : non-conformable arguments" from the following code:

```
library(lavaan)

model_02 <- 'i =~ 1*ghrelint0 + 1*ghrelint30 + 1*ghrelint60 + 1*ghrelint120
           s =~ 0*ghrelint0 + 1*ghrelint30 + 2*ghrelint60 + 4*ghrelint120
           q =~ 0*ghrelint0 + 1*ghrelint30 + 4*ghrelint60 + 16*ghrelint120

           i ~ dx
           s ~ dx
           q ~ dx
           i ~ bmi_percentile
           s ~ bmi_percentile
           q ~ bmi_percentile
           i ~ meal_energy
           s ~ meal_energy
           q ~ meal_energy
           i ~ batch_group
           s ~ batch_group
           q ~ batch_group
           ghrelint0 ~~ a*ghrelint0
           ghrelint30 ~~ a*ghrelint30
           ghrelint60 ~~ a*ghrelint60
           ghrelint120 ~~ a*ghrelint120'

fit_model_02 <- growth(model_02, data= be_ghrelin, estimator = "MLR", missing = "fiml")
summary(fit_model_02, fit.measures = TRUE)
standardizedSolution(fit_model_02)

predict(fit_model_02)
```

I cannot figure out how it's creating the ETA2 and LAMBDA matrices so I cannot resolve the fact that they may be different dimensions. I also can't figure out what the problems are in the code that they would've have been produced with different dimensions.

I'm running the predict function as a precursor to producing a graph of the growth model.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you have missing data (since you requested FIML).  Factor scores (etas) can only be estimated for complete cases.  You could also try running it without the 4 exogenous predictors.  `lavPredict()` tries to ignore the structural component when predicting factors scores (it is just designed for CFA models).  But I suspect missing data is the issue here.